# How to get the first key pair in array of JSON?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Currently, I have my JSON and a function that loops through the results and then through the URLs. I am trying to only get the first type value which is detail. I have tried looking for ways to get the first value and found that using `[0]` can work in some situations but not this one. Am I indexing incorrectly? and is there a more succinct way of coding this nested for loop?

```js
const data = {
  "data": {
    "results": [{
      "name": "Deadpool",
      "urls": [{
          "type": "detail",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/characters/12/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        },
        {
          "type": "wiki",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_(Wade_Wilson)?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        },
        {
          "type": "comiclink",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/comics/characters/1009268/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
};

function test(data) {
  const dataArr = data.data['results'];
  for (let i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
    console.log(dataArr[i].urls);
    const urlArr = dataArr[i].urls
    for (let j = 0; j < urlArr.length; j++) {
      console.log(urlArr[j].type[0]);
    }
  }
}

test(data);
```

Comment: Will the object always  be in the same format/schema?

Comment: You apparently have a JavaScript object literal, not a JSON, which is a textual data exchange format.

Comment: If you add a sample of the end-result you wish to have would be greatly help to understand your problem.

Comment: So you want to get the first `type` of each result? Or you want the whole url object for each result? What is it exactly that you're looking to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the exact element by `type` prop.

```js
const data = {
  "data": {
    "results": [{
      "name": "Deadpool",
      "urls": [{
          "type": "detail",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/characters/12/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        },
        {
          "type": "wiki",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_(Wade_Wilson)?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        },
        {
          "type": "comiclink",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/comics/characters/1009268/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
};

function test(data) {
  const dataArr = data.data['results'];
  for (let i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
    //console.log(dataArr[i].urls);
    const urlArr = dataArr[i].urls
    const detail = urlArr.find(url => url.type == 'detail');
    console.log(detail.url);
  }
}

test(data);
```

Comment: say for instance I later wanted all three types, I would have to do individual variables like this 

`const detail = urls.find(url => url.type === 'detail'); const detail = urls.find(url => url.type === 'wiki');` etc

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. All the 3 types are, basically, the `urls` property, isn't?

Answer (score 3):

### A functional approach...

Your question seems a little vague, but I think you're looking for the value of `type` from the first item in each `urls` array.

```js
const data = {
    "data": {
        "results": [{
            "name": "Deadpool",
            "urls": [{
                "type": "detail",
                "url": "http://marvel.com/characters/12/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
            },
            {
                "type": "wiki",
                "url": "http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_(Wade_Wilson)?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
            },
            {
                "type": "comiclink",
                 "url": "http://marvel.com/comics/characters/1009268/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
            }]
        }]
    }
};

const types = data.data.results.map(({ urls: [first, ...rest] }) => first.type);
console.log(types);
```

---

### Let's break this down...

```
data.data.results.map(...)
```

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will return a new array with the results of calling the provided function on every element in the `results` array.

```
({ urls: ... })
```

This is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It defines a new variable, `urls`, that is assigned the value of the `urls` property as we iterate through the `results` items.

```
({ urls: [first, ...rest] })
```

The value of the `urls` variable we defined will be an array. We only care about the first item in the array, so we'll [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array, defining a new variable called `first` that's assigned the value of the first item, and a variable, `rest`, that will be an array of the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of the items. Basically, take the head of the array. These operations are called [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), respectively.

```
({  urls: [first, ...rest] }) => first.type
```

Finally, return the value of the `type` property from the first `urls` item.

---

### If I'm completely wrong

And you want the "details" item within each `urls` array, then a slight change will suffice:

```js
const data = {
    "data": {
        "results": [{
            "name": "Deadpool",
            "urls": [{
                "type": "detail",
                "url": "http://marvel.com/characters/12/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
            },
            {
                "type": "wiki",
                "url": "http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_(Wade_Wilson)?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
            },
            {
                "type": "comiclink",
                 "url": "http://marvel.com/comics/characters/1009268/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
            }]
        }]
    }
};

const urls = data.data.results.map(({ urls }) => 
    urls.find(({ type }) => type === 'detail')
);
console.log(urls);
```

---

If you'd like to learn more about functional programming, Eric Elliott wrote an excellent set of articles on functional programming in JavaScript. Here's the [first one](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/composing-software-an-introduction-27b72500d6ea).

Answer (score 2):

If the format of your data is fixed you can use.
You can also try different approaches of safe reading data from object.
You can use utilities like [these](https://gist.github.com/ashish-r/91ee6ad307687061b765dcf32de40589):

```
data.data['results'][0].urls[0]
```

If you are not sure about the 0th index you can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
data.data['results'][0].urls.find(url => url.type === 'detail')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
function test(data) 
{
    var dataArr = data.data.results;

    for (let i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {

        const urlArr = dataArr[i].urls
        for (let j = 0; j < urlArr.length; j++) {
            console.log(urlArr[0].type);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const data = {
  "data": {
    "results": [{
      "name": "Deadpool",
      "urls": [{
          "type": "detail",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/characters/12/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        },
        {
          "type": "wiki",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_(Wade_Wilson)?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        },
        {
          "type": "comiclink",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/comics/characters/1009268/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
};

const result = [].concat.apply([], data.data.results.map(x => x.urls.map(y => y.type)))[0];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  "data": {
    "results": [{
      "name": "Deadpool",
      "urls": [{
          "type": "detail",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/characters/12/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        },
        {
          "type": "wiki",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_(Wade_Wilson)?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        },
        {
          "type": "comiclink",
          "url": "http://marvel.com/comics/characters/1009268/deadpool?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=6fa9bcf637a9185ee2e3035cb2d3b465"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
};

console.log(data.data.results.map(el => el.urls).flat().find(el => el.type === 'detail'));
```